# Is there a clean way to write multiline statements in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiline strings in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/multiline-strings-in-javascript)

I'm a php developer very new to js. In php I use heredoc a lot for multi-line variable values or print statements. In js, is there any way to easily write these without having to resort to messy code like this:

```
var animals = 'dog'+
              'cat'+
              'bird'+
etc...
```